# How to track an new/edited item in QTablewidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with  x rows and 2 columns. Sorting is enabled.
I want to add a new Item:

```
def addlabel(self):
  rows = self.cui.tableWidget.rowCount()
  self.cui.tableWidget.insertRow(rows)
  self.cui.tableWidget.setItem(rows-1,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("*New*"))
```

How can I track my new item without `findItems(text, flags)`? Is that possible?
Similar question:
After editing the new item, it may changes the position because of the sorting. How can I track my edited Item? (I want the new positions(rows))

Answer (score 1):

Return the item from the method and later you can do `item.row()` to get the row.

```
def addlabel(self):
  rows = self.cui.tableWidget.rowCount()
  self.cui.tableWidget.insertRow(rows)
  item = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("*New*")
  self.cui.tableWidget.setItem(rows-1,0,item)
  return item

# ...

# somewhere...
  label = self.addlabel()
  print label.row()
```